# failed to load database information. error in file temp xxxxxxxxxx

Tags: mysql, vb.net

```
 Dim dt As New DataTable

        With dt
            .Columns.Add("Itemname")
            .Columns.Add("Quantity")
            .Columns.Add("Price")
            .Columns.Add("Total")
        End With

        For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In Me.DataGridView1.Rows
            dt.Rows.Add(dr.Cells("Itemname").Value, dr.Cells("Quantity").Value, dr.Cells("Price").Value, dr.Cells("Total").Value)
        Next

            Dim rptdoc As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
        rptdoc = New ordersprint
            rptdoc.SetDataSource(dt)
```

can somebody help me with this ? here's my code in printing the data in datagridview ?

Answer (score 0):

Failed to load database is when your VB.net is not able to connect to database itself. The query execution comes later. Check if connection string is proper and MySQL db is able to listen to connection request from outside localhost.

Comment: I'm passing the datagridview data to crystal report to print. the datagridview is not connected into database. when I remove passing the datagridview values to to crystal report printing. there is no error.